# Increase Like count if post id is equal to action.payload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am working on a social network app and I want to toggle the like count on clicking(it should increment by 1 on first click and should go back to null to when pressed again) for a particular post. But now when i click on the like button, nothing happens and the screen gets vanish. I am unable to get what is wrong with my code.

Here are my files-> action creator

```
export const fetchPosts = () => async dispatch => {
  const request = await axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/post`, {
    headers: { Authorization: `${token}` }
  });
  dispatch({
    type: FETCH_POSTS,
    payload: request
  });
};



export const incrementLikesCount = id => {
  return {
    type: INCREMENT_LIKES_COUNT,
    payload: id
  };
};
```

index.js(reducer)

```
import auth from "./authReducer";
import user from "./userReducer";
import post from "./postReducer";

export default combineReducers({
  auth,
  user,
  post,
  form: formReducer
});
```

postreducer.js

```
import _ from "lodash";
import { FETCH_POSTS, INCREMENT_LIKES_COUNT } from "../actions/types";

const initialState = {
  postDetail: "",
  likesCount: null
};

const post = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_POSTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        postDetail: _.mapKeys(action.payload.data.data, "_id")
      };

    case INCREMENT_LIKES_COUNT:
      return _.values(state.postDetail)
        .reverse()
        .map(post => {
          if (action.payload === post._id) {
            if (state.likesCount === null) {
              console.log("I got executed");
              return { ...state, likesCount: state.likesCount + 1 };
            } else {
              return {
                ...state,
                likesCount: null
              };
            }
          } else {
            return {
              state
            };
          }
        });

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default post;
```

and my react Component

```
import _ from "lodash";
// import uuid from "uuid";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import {
  faHeart,
  faCommentAlt,
  faShareAlt
} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

import { fetchPosts, incrementLikesCount } from "../../../actions/FeedPost";
import "./FeedPosts.css";

class FeedPosts extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    if (!this.props.fetchPosts) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }
    this.props.fetchPosts();
  }

  renderPosts = () => {
    return _.values(this.props.post)
      .reverse()
      .map(post => (
        <div key={post._id} className="post-content">
          <img
            src={require("../../../img/blue.jpeg")}
            alt="user"
            className="user-image"
          />
          <span>{post.postBy}</span>
          <span>{post.userDesignation}</span>
          <li>{post.postText}</li>
          <div className="fontawesome-icons">
            <div className="like-font">
              <FontAwesomeIcon
                icon={faHeart}
                onClick={() => this.props.incrementLikesCount(post._id)}
              />
              <span>{this.props.likesCount}</span>
            </div>
            <div className="comment-font">
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCommentAlt} />
            </div>
            <div className="share-font">
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faShareAlt} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      ));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul className="posts">{this.renderPosts()}</ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  post: state.post.postDetail,
  likesCount: state.post.likesCount
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { fetchPosts, incrementLikesCount }
)(FeedPosts);
```

So, Basically my question is how can I increase the like count just for a particular post, because I was able to toggle the like button but it was increasing the like count of all the posts.

Comment: LikesCount is on state so should it not be:     case `INCREMENT_LIKES_COUNT:
      return {
        ...state,
        likesCount:state.likesCount+1
      }` if posts have a likes count and you'd like to increment the likes count then please let me know. It is also not clear where `state.posts` come from

Comment: @HMR , then what should it be? and yes I want to increment likes count on the post on clicking the like button

Comment: Why is it called `state.posts` and somewhere else it's called `state.postDetail`? And why is it an object, you keep converting it to array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should kind of work but it would be easier to have `state.posts` as array instead of converting from array to object and object to array every time.

To be sure it'll work you need to show the code where you set `state.posts`

```
case INCREMENT_LIKES_COUNT:
  return {
    ...state,
    likesCount:state.likesCount+1,
    //not sure why posts need to be an object instead of it being an array
    posts:Object.entries(state.posts).reduce(
      (result,[key,value])=>{

        if(value._id===action.payload){
          //you probably didn't set the initial likes but the reducer
          //  where you set state.posts isn't in your question
          result[key]= {...value,likes:value.likes+1};
        }else{
          result[key]=value;
        }
        return result;
      },
      {}
    )
  }
```

Although after seeing this again I realize the posts is an object where the id is the key so you can make it simpler:

```
case INCREMENT_LIKES_COUNT:
  return {
    ...state,
    likesCount:state.likesCount+1,
    //not sure why posts need to be an object instead of it being an array
    posts:{
      ...state.posts,
      [action.payload]:{
        ...state.posts[action.payload],
        likes:state.posts[action.payload].likes+1
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Okay, I think I need to give more info regarding this question. I am converting the array into object so I can _id as an index/key. I am getting a list of posts from server and I am displaying them on the screen. Each post has its id and each post has a like button, I want to increment the likeCount on clicking that like button, but when i tried to achieve this, all the post's likeCount was increasing(the behaviour which i obviously do not want). SO, I was asking why  I am unable to get the desired behaviour. I hope the question is clear now and  I have also updated the question.

Comment: @kamal11 The code to increase a like of a post is in the answer (twice). Not sure why you have an object called postDetail and posts on your state but you seem to render the posts in the component. There is no indication what the property indicating likes is on the post item so I just named it likes

Comment: Your code is doing the same thing as mine. It increases likes count of all the post but I just want to increase the likes count of a particular post. postDetail contains content of the post (eg: post_id, post_author, etc)

Comment: @kamal11 You should probably post what your state is with one or two posts and what your post reducer is getting. In your render you do `<span>{this.props.likesCount}</span>` that should be: `<span>{post.likes}</span>`

Comment: <span>{this.props.likesCount}</span> that should be: <span>{post.likes}</span>, this is only true when i am fetching the likes from backend but for now I want to display the likescount from redux state.

Comment: @kamal11: post item likes is (re)set by `result[key]= {...value,likes:value.likes+1};` in the first example of my answer and by `likes:state.posts[action.payload].likes+1` in the second. I thought `state.likesCount` is the total number of likes of all posts.

Comment: This is how the post looks like:  { "likesCount": 0,"commentsCount": 1, "likes": [], "comments": [ {"user": {"commentedOn": "2018-10-19T08:44:22.619Z",  "avatarPath":"uploads/1539691455295.png", "designation": "ENTTT", "id": "5bc4822309f07600132e525f",  "name": "SpartaYesMan"},"_id":"5bc9b6f7c7ef0b0013f28088", "text": "everything is fine", "__v": 0} ],  "_id": "5bc72cbaa79914001306d7c8",  "postText": "What is happening", "postBy":"KamalYadav","postById":"5bc4822309f07600132e525f","userDesignation": "Hero", "__v": 1} First I will send the likesCount to backend only then I can grab it from there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182141/discussion-between-hmr-and-kamal11).